# Attempting to loop and print an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to loop through a dynamic element and then print it with jquery,

Heres the code i use

```
$('.recipe-steps #addNewStep').on('click', function () {
            var s = $('.recipe-steps .step').size() + 1;
            $('<div class="step pure-u-1-1"><textarea id="step" name="step_detail[]" class="pure-u-1" placeholder="Step ' + s + '"></textarea><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" title="Remove">&times;</a></div>').appendTo($('.recipe-steps .steps'));
            return false;
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.step .remove', function () {
            $(this).parents('.step').remove();
            return false;
        });
```

however its only printing out the first element and not the preceding ones. I have created a fiddle can anyone see why?

http://jsfiddle.net/drk8X/

Comment: Only one element can have a given id. And there's no reason for .parents to look for siblings.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to come up with the perfect solution (will have a look later) but I have redesigned the function to work to an extent.

```
$("body").on('input propertychange', function () {
      var outputme="";
      $('textarea').each(function (index) {
            outputme+='<br>'+(index+1) + '. ' + $(this).val();
      });
      $('#lp-step').html('<h3>Method</h3>'+outputme);
  });
```

This will update the "preview" on change of the text area, use [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to narrow down the scope, but id reccomend you looking at your HTML and try and simplify it a bit more.

http://jsfiddle.net/drk8X/2/

Comment: also when i try it in my project it starts on .2 and 1. is blank

Comment: Do you know any way i could fix this?

Comment: On the JFiddle it works fine, put your code into jsfiddle.net/ and try adn get it replicated